# I want FeedItem/FeedComments to be Approved using Apex Salesforce how can we achieve it?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to approve feedItem/feedcomment using Apex but I am not able to create an Approval Process for them. So an idea of how we can submit feed records for Approval.

Answer (score 0):

FeedItem has a status field with two values *PendingReview* and *Published*. Change status to *Published* to approve them.
Example:

```
                List<FeedItem> feedItems = new List<FeedItem>();
                for(String feedId : feeds){
                    if(doApprove){
                        feedItems.add(new FeedItem(Id=feedId,Status='Published')); 
                    }
                }
                
                Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.update(feedItems, false);
```